# QML: How to access context property if its name is shadowed by a component-local property?

Tags: qt, syntax, properties, qml, shadowing

My code:

*main.cpp*:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("text", "hey");

    return app.exec();
}
```

*main.qml*:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Text {
        text: text
    }
}
```

Of course, the `text: text` line doesn't do what I want it to, because of name shadowing.

I worked around that by setting a property on the root object, rather than on the root context, and using `text: window.text`.

**Is there any real fix though?**

Comment: Not a direct answer, but: a code convention that we apply is to prefix the context variables with an underscore (so in your case it would be called "_text"). This in practice avoids conflicts *and* it makes very clear that the property is coming from C++, so it's pointless to look for it in the QML code.

Comment: A better answer would instead be to use qmlRegisterSingletonType rather than setContextProperty. The advantage in this case is that can use a qualified import to access the singleton and its properties, resolving your name clash.

Comment: Also, singletons are supposed to be even faster for lookup.

Comment: Do you have a source on that @ddriver ?

Comment: For me singleton and context properties are not interchangeable from a design point of view. My context properties are part of my C++ logic layer. The singletons are instantiated and owned by the QML layer, the fact that their are implemented in c++ is just an implementation detail.

Comment: @GrecKo - context properties can be changed, whereas singletons are static constructs, which allows for a greater level of access optimization. I have no source, nor have I tested it, but that's what I've read and it makes sense too.

Comment: @peppe: A convention like an underscore is a workable option, thanks. Though I prefer the `window.text` way because that way I don't have to remember a convention. I don't want to use a singleton, since in the future I may need to pass more than one object of this type to QML, and also, my object isn't logically a singleton although there's just one of it at present.

Comment: @StefanMonov a clearly visible convention does not only avoid lookup ambiguity, it also helps to easily identify C++ dependencies when reading the QML code. E.g. easy to spot which values would have to be provided by the C++ code of a unit test, etc.

Comment: The singleton doesn't necessarily has to be a "one value" object. I use singletons as value or function groups, when they need to be accessed project wide. For example, app settings, type factories, caches, prototypes... The singleton might be a static construct, but its content is not necessarily static, it can be very much dynamic, with the singleton being used as a shared access point to the underlying dynamic data.

Answer (score -1):

You don't. Using `text` for the name of a context property is like the worst possible choice. You'd literally do better by using `blahblah`. Why invite trouble?

You can implement an alias  to access the context property in the root object while also exposing the root object as a dynamic scope property. This will have the advantage of still being able to use the context property <s>while avoiding the expensive dynamic property lookup all the way down to the root</s> , while still providing an alternative<s>, albeit a less efficient</s> way to get to the context property in the cases where it is shadowed.

Update: Actually there is logical reason to assume that context properties are any faster to lookup than a regular dynamic scope object property. In this aspect, the above paragraph can only be used to provide a secondary identifier to access the shadowed property.

As mentioned in the comments, a singleton will actually make the most sense in this usage context, as it is directly resolved from an import rather than involving lookups, plus you can `import as` which can be useful to solve name conflicts. If you want to have multiple objects exposed via a singleton, instead of exposing each one as a separate singleton you can just have the different objects members of the singleton, such can be added dynamically as properties, model items or whatever serves the particular need.

Comment: `text: text` is just what I used in this minimal example. In the real code it's `sharedGLData: sharedGLData`. By "exposing the root object as a dynamic scope property" do you just mean "assigning an id to the root object"? If so, then that *is* a valid solution, thanks (although I don't really like it). It does have the performance advantage you describe.

Comment: I mean both assigning an id, and assigning it to a property of that object. Typically, you cannot access an object by id from another source, thus the need of the property, named so that it doesn't get shadowed. As for the name, what was implied there is that it is bad practice to name things in a way that is known to be prone to name resolution conflicts. Try `C_sharedGLData`, which also tells you that it is a context property.